# GCP: GCE: COS: Docker: Change which container is automatically started?

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, automation, google-compute-engine

I have a Docker Container that automatically restarts when the GCE VM instance is reset. That is good, but any changes to it are not permanent. If I commit the container using the base image repository and tag name, a new image is created with those labels and the base image loses its tag which goes to . Which would still be fine if I could run a new container from it and then make it autostart.

How would I change or add restarting to a different container than is generated when I use the 'Automatically Restart' option. I am using the Container OS and entering the docker.io/library/repo:tag entry in 'Container Image'.

The container is named with klt--nvfp. Maybe I can just rename another container to that? Or maybe there is an init file somewhere setting which container to load on startup.

EDIT: well that was a bad idea. Using 'docker rename' to switch two container names, now the klt--nvfp is gone, and my container with additions is Status: Removal In Progress. And to boot, the new image that was create on commit reverted its labels to  and the base image labels are restored to original. ..okay, now my additions container is gone and the klt--nvfp container is back without the changes I tried to commit to it. ..observation: its actually creating a new container every time on automatic restart.

Comment: Try something like this when you create that container. Using `--restart always ` will restart your container unless you explicitly wants to stop it. Useful in case of crash container, docker daemon start/stop
https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/start-containers-automatically/#use-a-restart-policy

Comment: @fly2matrix, do you know if its possible to add that flag to an existing container?

Comment: Apparently it can be 'updated' to add or remove if failing: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53004672/4240654

Answer (score 2):

I found one half solution workaround:

Under 'Custom metadata' in the instance settings, I entered this key and value:

```
startup-script  

#! /bin/bash
echo "starting"
docker start thirsty_lehmann
```